# Lua Editor for Corona SDK (Eclipse Indigo Plugin)

Tags: eclipse-plugin, lua, coronasdk, eclipse-indigo

Can anyone suggest a good editor to use with Lua scripting specifically for the Corona SDK or aid me with an error I'm having trying to install the eclipse plugin. I would like to use Eclipse Indigo (64bit) preferably but I've had problems with the Lua plugin. I've got the lua site added to Eclipses download sites, but when I try to install it says it "can't be installed in this enviroment because its filter is not applicable" Anyone have any insight into that error with this plugin? I've searched and found information about the error with other plugins but fixes and reasons behind it didn't seem to apply to my problem.

Comment: I'd Google "Corona IDE" and look around, or ask on the Corona forums. Your question is a very bad match for Stackoverflow's format.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I was downloading the wrong lua editor for Eclipse. LuaEclipse was the problem so I used
http://www.eclipse.org/koneki/ldt/
and everything worked.

Answer (score 3):

[Notepad++](http://notepad-plus-plus.org/) is really useful. Lightweight and has lots of options.

For working with **Eclipse**

http://flashapplications.de/?p=946

there are some **Corona specific IDEs** available

[Corona Project Manager](http://coronaprojectmanager.com)

[Cider](http://www.mydevelopersgames.com/CIDER/)

[Corona Complete](http://coronacomplete.com/)

**Other Editors**

[TextMate](http://www.macromates.com)(Mac - has a Corona plugin)

[BBEdit](http://itunes.apple.com/au/app/bbedit/id404009241?mt=12)(Mac)

[TextWrangler](http://itunes.apple.com/au/app/textwrangler/id404010395?mt=12)(Mac)

There are a LOT of **Lua editors** available

http://www.wowwiki.com/Lua_editors

http://lua-users.org/wiki/LuaEditorSupport

And finally a link which you may find useful

http://producerism.com/blog/how-to-develop-in-corona-sdk-on-windows/

Answer (score 3):

THe [Zeus](http://www.zeusedit.com/lua.html) editor has support for Lua. The latest version also adds Lua debugger support.

Answer (score 3):

To add to Satheesh's list: [ZeroBrane Studio Lua IDE](http://studio.zerobrane.com) includes support for Corona SDK and provides syntax-highlighting, auto-complete, and debugging support.